# applying list of functions to list of arguments in python

Tags: python

I have the following lists

```
fncs = ["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","get","addAtTail"]
args = [[],[8],[1],[81]]
```

And I want to return

```
[MyLinkedList(), addAtHead(8), get(1), addAtTail(81)]
```

I thought I could use `fnc_vals = [f(x) for f, x in zip(fncs, args)]` but that doesn't seem to work since my fncs list is a list of strings. How can I apply a list of functions to a list of arguments (in Python)?

Comment: should `fncs` be a list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are in the local namespace, just remove the quotes:

```
fncs = [MyLinkedList, addAtHead, get, addAtTail]
args = [[], [8], [1], [81]]
```

If the 1st list *must* be strings, you can get the function objects with:

```
function_names = ["MyLinkedList", "addAtHead", "get", "addAtTail"]
functions = [locals()[fn] for fn in function_names]
```

*If*, that is, the functions are named in the local namespace.

Comment: What if the functions are a list of strings and I can't change that?

Comment: Updated getting functions from locals by name.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of strings refering to the current scope functions you can use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

```
fnc_vals = [golbals()[f](x) for f, x in zip(fncs, args)]
```

Check this example:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> globals()["foo"](10)
10
```

You can also build your own functions addressing dictionary:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> def bar(x):
...     return x + 10
... 
>>> func_dict = {f.__name__:f for f in (foo, bar)}
>>> func_dict["foo"](10)
10
```